# App size too big using latest SDK

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

App build with 6.6.1.SDK is almost 51.39MB on android device, the same app build with 5.5.1.SDK it is around 40MB. Size increases about 10MB if I use latest SDK, any solution?

Comment: 6.6.1 SDK doesn't exist. Do you mean 6.1.1? Also, it heavily depends on the modules you use probably. An empty app is still pretty small and hasn't increased much, if at all.

Comment: Read this sweet blog if you do care about APK size: **[Reduce Titanium Build Sizes](https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2017/07/optimising-titanium-app-file-sizes/)**

Comment: My bad SDK is 6.1.1.GA.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this post interesting -- some advice for reducing the size of Android builds including generating two builds under one Play Store listing that are optimised for specific architectures.

https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2017/07/optimising-titanium-app-file-sizes/